# "quasi-enum" in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

When I call a function with a `System.Drawing.Color` or `System.Drawing.Brush` parameter, Visual Studio automatically brings up the list of pre-defined colors/brushes, like with an enum, even though `Color` is a struct and `Brush` is a class.

How can I achieve the same effect with my own struct/class?

**EDIT**

I figured that this is VB specific, seems like IntelliSense works quite differently in C#. I added screenshots for clarity.

With Color it works:

[image: ok]

My own struct doesn't work:

[image: not ok]

Comment: I believe they're static fields on the `Color` and `Brush` class and intellisense is picking that up.

Comment: Add static public properties to your struct or class.

Comment: You can also look at the [source code for `Color`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs) to see how it's done

Comment: @Haney But when I do that to my own struct it doesn't work (VB).

Comment: @Dave when you do what? Please show sample of code that does not do what you want.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I added some screenshots. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Which part doesn't match? It has exactly the same modifiers. (I omitted Public since that is the default - but even if I type it out, it doesn't make a difference.) And I inserted pictures becuse the point is about IntelliSense, not my code.

Comment: Sorry it's VB... indeed all is public - I'm not sure how this post got into questions I look at as it is not marked C#...

Answer (score 2):

By having `public static` fields or properties.

Color in particular uses public read only properties.  See [Color.AliceBlue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aliceblue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example

Comment: I personally prefer [Crimson](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.crimson(v=vs.110).aspx), but have a +1 anyways!

Comment: @C.Ross Weird, I just tried in C# and it doesn't work. I fact, not even Color and Brush work. To get the list of colors I have to type in "color.", unlike in VB.

Answer (score 1):

They are properties with, The XML documentation specifies the color to be displayed in the drop down list of the Intellisense.

From [Microsoft Source - System.Drawing.Color:](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Color.cs)

```
/// <include file='doc\Color.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Color.AliceBlue"]/*' />
/// <devdoc>
///    <para>[To be supplied.]</para>
/// </devdoc>
public static Color AliceBlue {
    get {
        return new Color(KnownColor.AliceBlue);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I see what you're saying now.  I will delete my comments.

Answer (score 0):

well for c# in the [color.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing) you will see

```
    /// <include file='doc\Color.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Color.AliceBlue"]/*' />
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>[To be supplied.]</para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public static Color AliceBlue {
        get {
            return new Color(KnownColor.AliceBlue);
        }
    }
```

example of a custom class:

```
public class foo
{
    public int a;

    public foo(int _a){a = _a;}

    public static foo preset1{ get{ return new foo(1); }}
    public static int getPreset1AsInt{ get{ return foo.preset1.a; }}

    public static foo preset2{ get{ return new foo(2); }}//this doesn't have to be New it can be a private static field!
    public static foo preset3{ get{ return new foo(3); }}




}
```

or you know what ever you want to do. this code is sloppy but I hope you get the idea